# How to make a page unscrollable when an element is on screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website about Caillou (its for school) and I have a loading animation for when the site is loading, I want the site to become unscrollable when it's open

So, when the site is loading it will become unscrollable, but when the site loads and gets rid of the loading animation it will be scrollable.

Here is my HTML

```
  <div id="epicloader">
    <div class="circle1">
      <div class="circle2"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
#epicloader{
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.circle1{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  animation: spin1 1s linear infinite;
  opacity: 1;
}

.circle2{
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 3px dotted #6e3030;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
  animation: spin2 4s linear infinite;
  opacity: 1;
}


@keyframes spin1{
  from{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin2{
  from{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50%{
    border: 3px dotted #1e62eb;
    border-right: 3px solid black;
  }
  to{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Here is my javascript

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("epicloader").style.display = "none";
 }
```

I've tried overflow: hidden in the #epicloader div, but that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to check what is scrolling!

I doubt it would be you div epicloader. More could be body.

So try to begin with body overflow hidden. When your page is loaded, you put it back to auto (or scroll, or only y).